# Етимологія слова "лицемір"

Tags: етимологія

Це слово утворене від *"лице"*? Я не знайшла етимологію. "Лице" вживається переважно в художніх творах. Походження цього слова я теж не знайшла.

В російській мові є слово *"лицемер"*. Українською воно звучить як *"лицемір"*. Але якщо лицо - це обличчя, то чому лицемер - лицемір?

Comment: Reopen за спробу виправити запитання. Тепер воно не про переклад, а про етимологію, і є більш зрозумілим.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слово *лицемір* має давнє словʼянське походження. [Словник Фасмера](http://starling.rinet.ru/cgi-bin/response.cgi?root=/usr/local/share/starling/morpho&morpho=1&basename=morpho%5Cvasmer%5Cvasmer&first=1&off=&text_word=%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80&method_word=substring&ic_word=on&text_general=&method_general=substring&ic_general=on&text_origin=&method_origin=substring&ic_origin=on&text_trubachev=&method_trubachev=substring&ic_trubachev=on&text_editorial=&method_editorial=substring&ic_editorial=on&text_pages=&method_pages=substring&ic_pages=on&text_any=&method_any=substring&sort=word&ic_any=on) пояснює його так:

> Походить від прасловʼянського кореня, від якого, у тому числі, походять: старословʼянське *лицемѣръ*, російське *лицемер*, українське *лицемíр*, болгарське, македонське *лицемер*, чеське *licoměřit* «лицемірити», польске *licemierzyć*.
>   Із `*lice` та `*-měnъ` (див. *мена* — міняти), тобто, **«той, що змінює обличчя, дволичний»**. Зближене з *meřa, meřiti* (див *міра*, рос. *мера*). Ср. лит. *veidmainỹs* — також.

Іншими словами, *«лице» + «міняти»*, а от *«міна»* (міняти) і *«міра»* (міряти, вимірювати) також споріднені, але більш далекі одне від одного.

Comment: @Follower, дякую. Там посилання страхітливе, включно з `root=/usr/local/share/`, і цікаво, чи можливо експлойтнути цю дірку в безпеці. :)